# Is it possible to morph SVG's paths using Velocity.js?

Tags: svg, velocity.js

Is it possible to morph SVG's paths using Velocity.js?

FROM 
`"M292,129c55.2,0,193,125.8,193,181S365.7,506,310.5,506S136,355.2,136,300S236.8,129,292,129z"`

TO
`"M230,38c55.2,0,348,57.8,348,113S391.2,569,336,569S55,456.2,55,401S174.8,38,230,38z"`

```
var path = document.querySelectorAll('svg path');

Velocity(path[0], {
    tween: 1000
}, {
    duration: 6000,
    easing: 'easeOutBounce',
    progress: function (el, c, r, s, t) {
        el[0].setAttribute('d', ??????);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Please note I am the author of the code that enabled this in 2016, so it is the official supported way to do it!

Almost, should be something like this:

```js
var path = document.querySelectorAll('svg path'),
  from = "M292,129c55.2,0,193,125.8,193,181S365.7,506,310.5,506S136,355.2,136,300S236.8,129,292,129z",
  to = "M230,38c55.2,0,348,57.8,348,113S391.2,569,336,569S55,456.2,55,401S174.8,38,230,38z";

Velocity(path[0], {
    tween: [to, from]
}, {
    duration: 6000,
    easing: 'easeOutBounce',
    progress: function(elements, complete, remaining, start, tweenValue) {
        elements[0].setAttribute('d', tweenValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please note that negative numbers as part of the string were bugged until Velocity 1.4.3

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Velocity has some string animation support built in, see Rycochets answer below.

If not you could try doing that yourself, by breaking down the path string into an array.

One way could be to use the path data polyfill (as Chrome has deprecated that feature to give easy access to the array points) at [polyfill](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill.js). Then you could loop similar to below through the path points and interpolate.

You could also try using some regex to split and then build back up, a quick example could be something like the following. It's probably not complete (I haven't really tested the regex, and you may get varying number of elements if there are some characters that I haven't thought of).

```
$velocity=$("#mypath");

var fromPath = "M292,129c55.2,0,193,125.8,193,181S365.7,506,310.5,506S136,355.2,136,300S236.8,129,292,129z";
var toPath = "M230,38c55.2,0,348,57.8,348,113S391.2,569,336,569S55,456.2,55,401S174.8,38,230,38z";

var re = /(([+-]?[0-9\.]+)|[a-z]|\s+)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?/gi

var fromMatch = fromPath.match(re)
var toMatch = toPath.match(re)

$velocity.velocity(
    { opacity: 0.5, tween: [0,1] },
    { progress: function( el, complete, remaining, start, tweenValue) { 
       var interpPath = '';
       for( c=0; c<fromMatch.length; c++) {
         if( !isNaN( fromMatch[c]) ) {
           interpPath += ( toMatch[c] - fromMatch[c] ) * tweenValue + +fromMatch[c]
         } else {
           interpPath += toMatch[c]
         }
       }
       el[0].setAttribute('d', interpPath)
    } }
)
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oon6sf7b/14/)

Comment: Sorry - had to downvote - I added the ability for Velocity to handle string->string animations several months ago, I don't have access to the documentation to add it there however. See https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/697

Comment: https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/commit/7b196f548a27bdbd909e0d82cf89f8ed8c427edf - though there's been a couple of fixes since. Pasting my example into the JSFiddle sample (and making it log to the console) works perfectly for the values: https://jsfiddle.net/jgmxy0yc/ - just open your console first...

Comment: Didn't 'have' to downvote, but as you're an author of the velocity code, I certainly respect it :). I do still think my answer is 'useful' though, as per SO requirements, so find a downvote a bit harsh, but life is short :). Note, your example I don't think would work for transitioning from a positive to a negative for example (but I may be wrong), so I do think it's useful still to have a custom alternative.

Comment: Sadly your answer got voted up when it's overly complicated, and was the manual way to duplicate the built-in Velocity code (which also handles non-fraction rgb/rgba() values as well as negatives). Unfortunately RegExp use like this tends to lead to later bugs - but more accurate RegExp (for a path etc) is less readable - `/(-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)|-?\.[0-9]+|[^0-9\.-]+|\.|-)/g` - why the internal code doesn't use RegExp, and also knows when from & to are the same to save processing between them etc.

Comment: But as mentioned, the velocity code doesn't work with common cases like transitioning from/to a negative, so is essentially broken. Is that more useful ? Stackoverflow works best with various answers imo. I will leave it at that anyway.

Comment: Meh, just did a test as it should work with negatives - and discovered that it's actually a bug that it doesn't - not enough people are aware of this hence not enough testing and it got through... Really hope I have enough time to fix it and release a new version this weekend...

Comment: The power of RegExp - I was missing a "-" in there, it's released, should make it's way to the CDNs soon lol